# More beautiful Multiple DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetimeoffset, datetime-parsing, datetimeformatter

I got multiple string date to convert to OffsetDateTime and I did that with multiple try and catch, I think I will not have other DateTimeFormatter to write. So, how to make that more beautiful ?

**code:**

```
public static OffsetDateTime convertStringDateToOffsetDate(String dateStr){
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").withLocale( Locale.US );
        DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        DateTimeFormatter f3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        DateTimeFormatter f4 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        DateTimeFormatter f5 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        DateTimeFormatter f6 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        OffsetDateTime myDate = null;
        try{
            myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f).toOffsetDateTime();
        } catch(DateTimeParseException e){
            try{
                myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f2).toOffsetDateTime();
            } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
                try{
                    myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f3).toOffsetDateTime();
                } catch (DateTimeParseException exc) {
                    try{
                        myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f4).toOffsetDateTime();
                    }  catch (DateTimeParseException exce) {
                        try{
                            myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f5).toOffsetDateTime();
                        } catch(DateTimeParseException excep){
                            myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f6).toOffsetDateTime();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return myDate;
    }
```

Comment: The code in your question will take the offset from the string in the first format but will in the 3rd and 6th case ignore the offset in the string and instead apply the offset for Europe/Paris. Was this intended??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static OffsetDateTime convertStringDateToOffsetDate(String dateStr){
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'][ ][HH:mm:ss][.][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][XXX][XX][X]").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, f).toOffsetDateTime();
}
```

This should handle all your patterns. No multiple formatters or regex is needed.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution to the problem, I am writing down this method for the future.

Comment: That exactly what I need. Thank you !

Comment: (1) You shouldn’t have `HH:mm:ss` optional (so not in square brackets) since it is in all the formatters in the question and you need at least hour of day to create an `OffsetDateTime`. (2) From parsing  `2021-05-01T12:00:00-08:00` I would have expected `2021-05-01T12:00-08:00`. But I got `2021-05-01T12:00+02:00`, so the right hour of day, but the wrong offset and therefore the wrong point in time.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare parts of the format string to be optional, using the `[]` syntax. This may simply get you to a single pattern that takes care of it all. However, this setup where one pattern has US locale but the others don't, that part is not going to fit in a single format string. So, you can reduce the # of format strings you have, but probably not to a single one.

Then, use a list, and a helper method, to achieve clean code:

```
private static final List<DateTimeFormatter> FORMATS = List.of(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").withLocale( Locale.US ),
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.][SSSSSS][XXX]").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")));

public static OffsetDateTime parse(String dateStr) throws DateTimeParseException {
  DateTimeParseException ex = null;

  for (var format : FORMATS) try {
      return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, format).toOffsetDateTime();
  } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    ex = e;
  }
  throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s my stab at it.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendOffsetId()
        .optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);

private static final ZoneId DEFAULT_ZONE = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");

public static OffsetDateTime convertStringDateToOffsetDate(String dateStr) {
    TemporalAccessor parsed
            = PARSER.parseBest(dateStr, OffsetDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);
    if (parsed instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
        return (OffsetDateTime) parsed;
    } else {
        return ((LocalDateTime) parsed).atZone(DEFAULT_ZONE).toOffsetDateTime();
    }
}
```

To try it out:

```
    String[] testStrings = {
            "2021-01-01T12:34:56.789-07:00",
            "2021-02-01T12:34:56",
            "2021-03-01T12:34:56-06:00",
            "2021-04-01T12:34:56.987654",
            "2021-05-01T12:34:56.789",
            "2021-06-01T12:34:56.987654-05:00"
    };
    
    for (String testString : testStrings) {
        System.out.format("%-32s -> %s%n", testString, convertStringDateToOffsetDate(testString));
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2021-01-01T12:34:56.789-07:00    -> 2021-01-01T12:34:56.789-07:00
> 2021-02-01T12:34:56              -> 2021-02-01T12:34:56+01:00
> 2021-03-01T12:34:56-06:00        -> 2021-03-01T12:34:56-06:00
> 2021-04-01T12:34:56.987654       -> 2021-04-01T12:34:56.987654+02:00
> 2021-05-01T12:34:56.789          -> 2021-05-01T12:34:56.789+02:00
> 2021-06-01T12:34:56.987654-05:00 -> 2021-06-01T12:34:56.987654-05:00
> ```

You notice:

- It handles all 6 formats from your question.
- For the strings that have a UTC offset in them, the offset is retained. For strings that haven’t got one, the correct offset for Paris is assumed (+01:00 in February and +02:00 in April and May).

I believe that it has the following advantages:

- I need only one formatter.
- I have written no format pattern string at all, just assembled my formatter from built-in parts.

The `DateTimeFormatter.parseBest` method that I use to parse will try first to create an `OffsetDateTime` and if unsuccessful, it will resort to creating and returning a `LocalDateTime`. In the latter case I will need to convert it. The downside of my solution is that I need to go through a `TemporalAccessor`, which is an interface that I consider low-level and that we usually should not use in application code.

The built-in `DateTimeFOrmatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` already handles the presence and absence of up to 9 decimals on the seconds. So by reusing this in my formatter I already handle the cases of no decimals and of 3 and 6 decimals.

One challenge of your requirement to use Europe/Paris time zone for the strings that haven’t got an offset in them is, while a `DateTimeFormatter` can have many default values, it cannot have a default time zone. The `withZone` method gives us a formatter with an *override zone*, but this is something else. That formatter will *enforce* the override zone on the result of either formatting or parsing. While it wasn’t clear from your question I was assuming that you didn’t want this.

**Edit: does the formatter need a locale?** I used `.toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)` for building the formatter from the builder. Technically the locale isn’t necessary in this case since my formatter doesn’t include any parts that depend on locale, and in the first version of this answer I had left the locale out (calling the no-arg `toFormatter` method instead). However I tend to agree with Arvind Kumar Avinash in the comment:

> Just small nitpicking: Please always use `Locale` with a date-time
> parsing/formatting type … because it is a `Locale`-sensitive type. It
> may not be relevant for the date-time strings dealt with in this
> solution but we should stick to it as if it were a rule.

It was probably just me being arrogant and assuming that the reader was able to determine that there were no locale-sensitive parts in the formatter. Supplying a locale is the better habit (otherwise at least stick in a comment why there isn’t one).

Comment: Marvellous! Cleanest of all the solutions on this page! Just small nitpicking: Please always use `Locale` with a date-time parsing/formatting type (whether it is the modern and vivid `DateTimeFormatter` or error-prone and notorious `SimpleDateFormat`) because it is a `Locale`-sensitive type. It may not be relevant for the date-time strings dealt with in this solution but we should stick to it as if it were a rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single try-catch inside a loop, where the exception gets ignored.

```
List<DateTimeFormatter> list = Arrays.toList<>(f, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6);
for(DateTimeFormatter formatter : list)
{
    try
    {
        myDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter).toOffsetDateTime();
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that exceptions have a bad performance (writing stacktrace to variable takes time), so maybe the comment from M. Dudek to use regex could be the better answer.